# Neo4j node and relationship structure

Tags: database-design, neo4j, graph-databases

In Neo4j, I have a person node, company node and a position node. So, a "person" has a "position" at a "company". I have a question about modelling the database and the relationships between these nodes.

I could set it up like this (cypher "pseudo code"):

```
(person)-[:WORKS_AT]-(company) 
(person)-[:HAS_TITLE]->(position) 
(company)-[:HAS_POSITION]->(position)
```

person has relationship HAS_TITLE and WORKS_AT, or like this:

```
(person)-[:HAS_TITLE]->(position)<-[:HAS_POSITION]-(company)
```

where there is no direct relationship between the person and the company, I will have to go through the position node to find the company.

I guess it depends a little bit of what I want to get out of the database, but is there a "correct/standard" way of doing this in a graph database?

#### Edit:

When searching in the database I want to get all the positions for a person. I want to return them as a collection like this:

```
    [
      { 
        company: 'some company', 
        position: 'some position at the company' 
      }, 
      { 
        company: 'some other company', 
        position: '' // empty position, I dont have the position data here 
      } ,     
      { 
        company: 'some other company', 
        position: 'some position at the company'
      }      
    ]
```

#### Edit 2:

To clarify a little bit: this is the data structure I get to work with (json). This is data for one person only, there are multiple people who can have the same position in different companies etc. I need to put it into Neo4j and make it searchable:

```
  {   
     "id": 123,
     "name": "Foo Bar",
     "email": "",
     "workhistory": {
        "positions": [
           {
              "company": "Company A",
              "employees": "",
              "type": "Privately Held",
              "start": 1356998400,
              "end": "",
              "position": "Position A",
              "description": "",
              "industry": "some industry"
           },
           {
              "company": "Company B",
              "employees": "",
              "type": "Privately Held",
              "start": 1356998400,
              "end": "",
              "position": "Position B",
              "description": "",
              "industry": "some industry"
           },
           {
              "company": "Company C",
              "employees": "",
              "type": "Privately Held",
              "start": 1341100800,
              "end": "",
              "position": "Position A",
              "description": "",
              "industry": ""
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

I want to be able to search for a "position" node with a "name" property called "Position A", then find all the people with this position and return their profile with the same structure it had when it was put into the database, give or take.

Same goes for "industry" and "company", I want to break those off into separate nodes as well. The database will have millions of people in it.

#### Edit 3

I'm thinking of maybe adding the position as a node, with a "name" property etc. And then also add the position name on the relationship from person to company. This will make it easy to query for work history, but will take extra space for each WORKED_AT relationship (the WORKED_AT.position property). With this structure I can do searches on a position node as well, and get all the people related to a certain position.

This will probably be ok for this easy structure, but then what about more "nested" values? Like Person lives in City located in State located in Country etc?

Comment: It does depend a lot on what you want to get out of the database.  FWIW, the design you've got here looks completely reasonable to me.  Can you elaborate your question a little bit?  If you link person and company through position, that looks like it's maybe workable.  what are you worried that you won't be able to do with this design?

Comment: I'm worried that I might end up with a person that I dont have the position data on, so there will be no node connecting the person and the company, even though he did work there, I just dont know what he did there. The reason I need position as a node is that I want to index it with a label and be able to search on it. I could ofc just put the position as a property on the relationship between person and company, but then I wont be able to search for it, without suffering performance.

Comment: If you always know the company the person worked for, then even if you're missing their position, you can link them via :WORKS_AT.  You could also create a dummy position "Unknown" (one per company) and then link that person to that position if you know they work for company X but don't know their title.  That way the linkage is always there even if you don't know what the value should be.

Comment: If you **don't** always know what company a person works for, then you're probably screwed.  If the info isn't in your dataset, then no graph design is going to help, because you just don't know.  :)

Comment: I always know what company a person works for, I think :) So, if there is a position present, create WORKS_FOR, if no position present, do not create WORKS_FOR, just the HAS_TITLE? Edited the question to show what I want to get out out the database.

Comment: I guess there also is something else I did not think about, I wanted to create unique position nodes. I guess that will break the way I wanted to get the company, since there is multiple companies connected to the same position.

Comment: I'm suggesting creating one "Unknown" position *per company*, not just one for all companies.

Comment: Yes, I guess I also have to create one position per company for all the other positions as well? Or else there might be multiple companies per position and I dont know which company is the right one for each person.

Comment: Please post some CSV or base data you're starting with, and I can give you some cypher hints on how to do this - not just the rough structure of your resulting graph.

Comment: Question updated. I do not have csv, but I have provided a json structure I want to put into the DB.

Comment: This feels too broad for SO, you could try over on the Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/neo4j . However don't be shy of having lots of relationships and "nesting" as that is what Graphs are all about.

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this, I think the "correct" way of doing it is the way that feels most natural for your data and your app. As far as performance is concerned, traversing two relationships instead of one to find the company will not have any added impact unless a position is shared by so many companies that there's intense logic to determine which one is associated with that user.

But the deciding factor should be whether you have data that is unique to the relationship of the person and the company. The first thing I'd think of is a `hired_on` property to track how long a person has been there. You may want to see that independently of the person's position -- I'd put a `started_on` property between the person and the position -- but don't you want a person's work history? Things like salary, phone extension, office number... they could all go in properties on that relationship. You wouldn't put them on the `HAS_TITLE` relationship since you'd lose those if the title changes. They could also be properties on `person`, but couldn't people work for multiple companies?

Comment: yes, I do have properties on the relationship, like start and end date. They will probably be the same even for relationship between person and position and person and company. A person can have multiple positions, both current and in the past, for the same or different company. A position could potentially have a lot of companies connected to them. When doing queries, I usually match the person node first.